# How to execute a script located in the runner from the ci-pipeline?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-runner image as follows:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk add --no-cache curl bash

COPY trigger-jenkins /usr/local/bin/trigger-jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Its purpose is to trigger a Jenkins job. Running this with:

```
docker run -ti jenkins-runner:latest trigger-jenkins job_name
```

works perfectly fine. But when I tried to do the same by:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
Jenkins Trigger:
  script:
    - trigger-jenkins job_name
  tags:
    - Jenkins
```

The pipeline fails like this:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.3.0 (3df822b)
  on Jenkins Trigger (12475d61)
Using Docker executor with image jenkins-runner:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:44dedf0b3485e0e57107e2745739e1a252fb64c4161465e1b5ccc1119a1183bf for predefined container...
Using docker image jenkins-runner:latest ID=sha256:4760a8ef9139ee9c9a56c686de780fc49e176fe4294e1f0db4f431e117b6811c for build container...
Running on runner-12475d61-project-6-concurrent-0 via cc960a3794a0...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/dev/Project'...
Checking out 874b2eac as test/jenkins...
Skipping Git submodules setup
/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 126
```

I searched for the error code, but was not able to find an explanation.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have not specified the image in your yaml?

Comment: I have registered the runner with the tag `Jenkins`. As you can see in the log, the correct image is loaded.

Comment: The file is a executable file or a shell script?

Comment: trigger-jenkins is an executable shell script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was not because of exec. The issue was probably this, your entrypoint was `/bin/bash` and Gitlab CI was trying to execute `/bin/sh` which is an executable. Leads to something like below

```
/bin/bash /bin/sh command args
```

Which is what the complaint we see as. Cannot execute binary file. What your `entrypoint` should have been is below

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Which would have made sure a command gets execute by bash and whether it is another shell or bash it would have worked. No need to modify and created `entrypoint.sh`

Comment: this fix solved this problem for me, but then gave another error, eventually the solution for me was to use `ENTRYPOINT [""]` discussion on issue is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1170)

Comment: The failure would happen in the case where `/bin/bash` is not available in the image

Comment: I see.. i was building a container with both Python and Java

Comment: I have the same issue - and I was using the exec form of ENTRYPOINT and it has not worked. I seem to be getting a completely different error ...
set: Illegal option -o pipefail 
Unfortunately - the unnecessary complexity in understanding the nuances of the Docker DSL re:ENTRYPOINT fails the maxim "Don't Make Me Think" which results us end-users have to cope with unnecessary lengthy development times.

Answer (score 1):

I continued my research and found the repository of the official maven docker images.

They solved a similar problem by creating a `mvn-entrypoint.sh`. So I tried the same:

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/

exec "$@"
```

This did the trick.

Comment: I am clutching straws - now - am just going to try this - spent the whole w/e and no-where closer - I think it's an bug of gitlabrunner which cannot use sh shell properly for images derived from debian. See

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1170

looks like this issue is still unresolved - the gitlabrunner provided by our platform team is Running with gitlab-runner 13.3.1 (738bbe5a)